# Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) - Creating Posts above the image in a scroll

Tags: html, css

I want to ask how to display the text above the image and the file is located inside a scrollbar like the picture below.
I've searched on google and used position but it did not work. I hope you can help me to find a solution.

*Pictures and texts contained in scroll*
[image]

Comment: They didn't teach you that in scrool?

Comment: Google for "CSS figure". (and never mind the typo's, we're all nerds anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Add a parent div and set the background to an image. Then you can add a child/nested div or a heading tag with your text in it.

See the below pseudo code. I did not test the code but it should be enough to get you on the right track.

**CSS**

```
#container-img{   
   height: 500px; /* set the height you want the image to be */
   width: 500px; /* set the width of the image */
   background: url('your-img-src-here.png') no-repeat center center; 
         /* you can add whatever sizing and alignment after the url*/
}
#child-txt{
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: bold; 
   text-align: left;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container-img">
   <div id="child-txt"> Cool Text Here! </div>
 </div>
```

If it answers your question, please be sure to mark it as the answer. =)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create a block with picture and a text.

Give your block **position: relative** and your text **position: absolute**.

What about scrollbar - it means that you have a container where all your photos are, but it is small, so you use **overflow: scroll**.

see here code example: https://codepen.io/alex_ukr/pen/QgVzeL

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.main-container {
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 5px solid red;
  background-color: white;
}
.picture-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="picture-container">
    <img src="https://uploads.scratch.mit.edu/users/avatars/1385/1878.png" alt="">
    <span>your text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="picture-container">
    <img src="https://uploads.scratch.mit.edu/users/avatars/1385/1878.png" alt="">
    <span>your text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="picture-container">
    <img src="https://uploads.scratch.mit.edu/users/avatars/1385/1878.png" alt="">
    <span>your text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="picture-container">
    <img src="https://uploads.scratch.mit.edu/users/avatars/1385/1878.png" alt="">
    <span>your text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```